# In zsh how can I run a script which is written for bash

Tags: bash, zsh

I have switched to zsh, how can I run a script which is written for bash?

I don't want to modify the script to put #!/bin/bash in the beginning for the script since it is version controlled.

Is there another way?

The line of the script having problem is:

```
for f in `/bin/ls v/*/s.sh v/*/*/v.sh d/*/*/v.sh 2> /dev/null`
```

Comment: This line is terrible! It's terrible bash practice to parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: I agree with @gniourf_gniourf. While it's a bit outside the scope of this question, you would be better off doing this: `for f in v/*/s.sh v/*/*/v.sh d/*/*/v.sh` (this uses the built in glob-substitution of `bash`)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can run the script with bash manually:

```
bash myscript.sh
```

A better and more permanent solution is to add a shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Once that line is added, you can run it directly, even in ZShell:

```
% ./myscript.sh
```

As far as version control goes, you should commit this line, for the good of all the developers involved.

Comment: Agreed -- a script that requires bash, but doesn't start with a bash shebang, should be considered broken. And broken scripts should be fixed. (Though as @gniourf_gniourf pointed out, that's not the only problem here.)

Comment: As long as we are on the subject of shebangs: Why not correct to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. That way  the scripts work on more systems. (/usr/local/bin/bash, /usr/bin/bash etc are all hardcoded and you need to fix each script for each shell you use. With env you only have to maintain one single program).

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the solution commented by @neersighted, you should also make sure your bash script has the executive permission to run in the `zsh`. Thus, you should first set the first line of your bash script with shabang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Then run:

```
% chmod +x myscript.sh
```

to provide such permission. Then you can run it in `zsh` as:

```
% ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: saved me a lot of time

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which specifically stated: "I don't want to modify the script to put #!/bin/bash in the beginning for the script since it is version controlled."

Comment: Future me will be back here sometime. ..

Comment: @JonBentley This does actually answer the question.  You don't necessarily have to add the first line with the shebang (`#!/usr...`).  This should still work with just the `chmod +x myscript.sh`.  I tested this out and on my system it does work, and I don't think I have anything funky/different than normal that would let me run this without that shebang at the beginning.  I did just use a simple file and a simple test in the file, nothing complex.  This might be different with a more complex example.