# How can I run a bash script in zsh?

Tags: script, zsh

I want to run a script written for bash in zsh.

If I run *which bash*, I get

> /usr/bin/bash

Following this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/522715/776696) I have created the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo 'Hello'
```

The file *hello* is in the directory *~/.scripts* and the PATH variable is

```
~/.scripts: ...
```

and the defn of hello is

```
rwxr-xr-x 1 jeff jeff 30 Nov 21 15:04 hello
```

In bash I run

```
$ hello
```

and it works correctly

In zsh if I run

```
% hello
```

I get the error

> zsh: command not found: hello

but in zsf  if I run

```
% bash hello
```

it works correctly

What is wrong?

Comment: Is this a typo? `#!/usr/bin bash` It should be `#!/usr/bin/bash`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane thanks edited question

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: Are you sure that when you use zsh, `~/.scripts` is in your PATH? It probably loads a different .rc file from bash, so may not be setting the PATH the same.

Comment: Yes, run echo $PATH in zsh and it starts ~/.scripts:~/...

Answer (score 3):

The literal tilde in your `PATH` is expanded by Bash, but not by Zsh. In general you shouldn't use `~` inside `PATH`. Use the full path.

In an assignment tilde-prefixes can be used at the beginning of the word (that is, following the `=` of the assignment) and/or following any unquoted `:`; tildes will be expanded at the time of the assignment and won't get to `PATH` in their literal form. This is deliberately to make this syntax

```
PATH=~/.scripts:"$PATH"
```

work even if whatever uses the `PATH` doesn't expand `~` later. The point is there will be no `~` to expand; there will be the already expanded path instead of the tilde in `PATH` in the first place.

But the syntax like this:

```
PATH="~/.scripts:$PATH"
```

creates `PATH` with a literal tilde. Bash does expand the tilde at runtime, Zsh doesn't.

Fix your definition of `PATH`, so it doesn't contain any tilde character. `echo $PATH` should print `/home/psionman/.scripts:…` or so.

Comment: bash only works with "~/.scripts" in PATH. it will not find the file with " /home/psionman/.scripts"

Comment: @Psionman Is your home directory `/home/psionman/`?

Comment: I have  /home/psionman/.scripts in PATH in zsh, but it doesn't find the file

Comment: /home/psionman/ is my home directory

Answer (score 2):

You need not only to create the script, but also to make it executable. Then, when you run it, the `#!` line will instruct the system where to find an interpreter for the code.

Worked example:

```
cat >demo <<'EOF'    # Reads lines into the file "demo" until "EOF"
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo 'Hello from a script run by bash'
EOF

chmod a+rx demo      # Make the script available (readable and executable) for everyone

./demo               # Run it
```

Output

```
Hello from a script run by bash
```

Notice that as a user (not the programmer) you do not specify the interpreter to run the script on the command line - you absolutely do not need to know that it's written for `bash`.

You need `./demo` and not just `demo`. This is because UNIX/Linux and Mac systems - unlike Windows - typically do not include the current directory (`.`) in the set of places to search for a program. The set of searched directories is specified in the `$PATH` variable as a colon-separated list.

If you had `/usr/local/bin` in that list, and you moved the `demo` file to that directory, you could just run `demo` as for any other system program. Likewise, if you had `$HOME/bin` as a directory you could put it there too. Note that `~` is not necessarily a valid indicator in `$PATH` for your `$HOME` directory. It's valid for POSIX shells (and including `bash` and `zsh`) but not elsewhere:

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/bin"      # Or for many shells, mkdir -p ~/bin

PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"    # Acceptable everywhere
PATH=~/bin:"$PATH"        # Acceptable if set by a shell that handles ~
PATH="~/bin:$PATH"        # Invalid almost everywhere (works for bash, fails for zsh)
```

In the first two assignment examples, `$HOME` and `~` are expanded by the shell and the resulting `$PATH` has a set of explicit concrete directory paths. In the third assignment, the first directory path is still `~/bin` and although it's understood by `bash`, it may not be understood by everything else that might need to execute a program. The solution here is to fix how you're double-quoting the assignment (don't have `~` inside double quotes).

Comment: I have updated my question with location of the script and my PATH variable

Comment: @Psionman I have updated the tail of my answer for you. The reason is that you have a literal `~` in your `PATH`